# Installers asks me to insert CD that is already in tray

Tags: dvd, cd, installation

I have tried installing Ubuntu 11.04 server and Ubuntu 10.04 server on a fairly old AMD Athlon machine but after quite som time of the install the installer asks me to insert the install disk, which is already in the drive. I have tried both from a burnt CD and a burnt DVD disk with same outcome. Checked integrity of the disks and the mem of the computer and everything ok.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Fixed via different installation → voted to close as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your DVD drive is dodgy? try installing from USB with Unetbootin. Log into Windows or whatever it is your using, point Unetbootin to your ISO and wait. Once done, reset and boot via USB. You will also find this method much faster than CD or DVD

Comment: I managed to install over the net using the minimal cd. Thanks.